# Spring controller how to get and convert JQuery dataTable aoData into Java object

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables

I have this js code:

```
                table = $('#searchResultTable').dataTable(
                    {
                        "destroy" : true,
                        "bProcessing" : true,
                        "bServerSide" : true,
                        "sDom" : 'trtip',
                        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                        "sServerMethod" : "POST",
                        "sEmptyTable" : "No Entity Profile found",
                        "iDisplayLength" : searchBO.pagination.pageSize,
                        "sAjaxSource" : "search.jax",

                        "fnServerParams" : function(aoData) {
                            aoData.push({
                                "name" : "searchBO",
                                "value" : searchBO
                            });
                        },
                        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData,
                                fnCallback, oSettings) {
                            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                                "contentType" : "application/json",
                                "dataType" : "json",
                                "url" : sSource,
                                "type" : "post",
                                "data" : aoData,
                                "success" : fnCallback,
                                "error" : function(a, b, c) {
                                    alert("error!");
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData,
                                iDisplayIndex) {
                            $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html(
                                    '<a href="viewProfile-'
                                            + aData.encEntityId + '.htm">'
                                            + aData.entityId + '</a>');
                            return nRow;
                        }
                    });
```

searchBO would be something like this:

```
var searchBO = {
    "pagination" : pagination,
    "individual" : individual,
    "organization" : organization,
    "enrollmentId" : enrollmentId,
    "medicareId" : medicareId,
    "npi" : npi,
    "contractId" : contractId,
    "firstName" : firstName,
    "lastName" : lastName,
    "ssn" : ssn,
    "dob" : dob,
    "licenseNumber" : licenseNumber,
    "licenseState" : licenseState,
    "specialtyType" : specialtyType,
    "licenseExpirationDate" : licenseExpirationDate,
    "businessName" : businessName,
    "ein" : ein,
    "organizationType" : organizationType,
    "city" : city,
    "state" : state,
    "zipCode" : zipCode,
    "startDate" : startDate,
    "endDate" : endDate
}
```

On Chrome debug mode, I can see the data I'm passing to server is:

```
 Request Payload
 sEcho=1&iColumns=2&sColumns=%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=1&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&searchBO=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

Now I'm a little confuse about what the best way is for Spring controller to parse this data into a Java Object, Is this possible?I would like my controller something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search.jax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object doSearch(@RequestBody SearchRequestJSON searchRequestJSON,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws APSException {
    SearchResponseJSON json = new SearchResponseJSON();
    return json;
}
```

I've figured out the SearchResponseJSON.java would look like:

```
import java.util.List;
public class SearchResponseJSON {
private int sEcho;
private int iTotalRecords;
private int iTotalDisplayRecords;
private List<EntityProfileVO> aaData;



public int getiTotalDisplayRecords() {
    return iTotalDisplayRecords;
}

public void setiTotalDisplayRecords(int iTotalDisplayRecords) {
    this.iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalDisplayRecords;
}


public int getiTotalRecords() {
    return iTotalRecords;
}

public void setiTotalRecords(int iTotalRecords) {
    this.iTotalRecords = iTotalRecords;
}

public int getsEcho() {
    return sEcho;
}

public void setsEcho(int sEcho) {
    this.sEcho = sEcho;
}

public List<EntityProfileVO> getAaData() {
    return aaData;
}

public void setAaData(List<EntityProfileVO> aaData) {
    this.aaData = aaData;
}
}
```

I'm very not sure what the SearchRequestJSON.java needs to be like.I'm hoping in the controller @RequestBody can convert aoData from front-end into searchRequestJSON object.
thanks for any help.

Comment: Your datatable should be able to display the data in the format you provided - can you show the datatable initialisation code please?

Answer (score 0):

Use @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestBody

Comment: what should my SearchRequestJSON.java looks like based on the aoDate I saw in request payload

Comment: you are passing your data directly with  the request as a list of parameters. Provided you have a bean with properties with the same name as those youre passing (and getters and setters), Spring will bind them properly. The problem is, your searchBO object is being passed just as "Object" so what you need to do is send a request that passes your searchBO as json to your controller, and *then* use @RequestBody. If you have proper MessageConverters (I think Jackson comes directly with SpringMVC), Spring will map them into your beans.

Comment: I would suggest you use a browser extension that allows to send requests directly, and try embedding a json object whithin your post request, to see that Spring is properly handling it. Then do the same in your JS code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll do it so. I get rid of the SearchBO in JS and also related place in java. I'm using @ModelAttribute to parse this aoData. I'm seeing the value of aoData is not being parsed. Do you see anything else need to be done beside change @ RequestBody to @ ModelAttribute. Thanks again.